# Expresso Store: shipping_same_as_billing issue since upgrade to 2.3.1

Tags: expresso-store, tags, checkout

Since upgrading to 2.3.1 I've found that even if the customer unticks the 'shipping_same_as_billing' box then on the next screen they are told that the Shipping address is the same as the billing address.

This worked fine up to this upgrade.

Thanks in advance for your help

Code on checkout 2.

```
<div class="control-group same-billing">
            <div class="controls">
                <label for="shipping_same_as_billing" class="checkbox">
                    {field:shipping_same_as_billing} Same as Billing Details
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Code on checkout 3

```
 <div class="control-group">
                    {if shipping_same_as_billing}
ALWAYS SHOWS AS TRUE!
                        <p><strong>Same as Billing Details</strong></p>
                    {if:else}
                        <div><strong>{shipping_name}</strong></div>
                        <div>{shipping_address1}</div>
                        <div>{shipping_address2}</div>
                        <div>{shipping_address3} </div>
                        <div>{shipping_postcode}</div>
                        <div>{shipping_region_name}</div>
                        <div>{shipping_country_name}</div>
                        <div>{shipping_phone}</div>
                    {/if}
                </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok - found a fix for this.

This simple condition

```
 {if shipping_same_as_billing}
ALWAYS SHOWS AS TRUE!
                        <p><strong>Same as Billing Details</strong></p>
                    {if:else}
```

No longer works, but altering the condition to be more specific does.

```
{if shipping_same_as_billing == 1}
                        <p><strong>Same as Billing Details</strong></p>
                    {if:else}
```

Comment: What version of EE are you using?

Comment: EE 2.9 and Store 2.3.1